# Stored procedure is not incrementing more than 10 increment

Tags: sql, sql-server

Create the following stored procedure but the `@tagID` is not incremented for more than 10 serial from 1 - please help.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[bulk_employee]
    @active BIT,
    @FNAME NVARCHAR(50),     
    @DOB DATE,  
    @DOJ DATE,  
    @GENDER NVARCHAR(10), 
    @FATHER_NAME NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,  
    @AADHAR NVARCHAR(14),   
    @ESIC NVARCHAR(10) = NULL,  
    @UAN NVARCHAR(10) = NULL,
    @SALARY INT,    
    @BRANCH INT,     
    @DIVISION INT,  
    @USER INT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TagID INT;

    SELECT @TagID = COALESCE((SELECT MAX(Emp_ID) + 1 FROM EmployeeP1), 1)

    INSERT INTO EmployeeP1 (isActive, Emp_ID, FirstName, BirthDate, JoiningDate, Gender, FatherName, aadharnumber, ESIC, UAN, SalaryID, DivisionID, BranchID, AccessBy, LastUsed)
    VALUES ('0', @TagID, @FNAME, @DOB, @DOJ, @GENDER, @FATHER_NAME, @AADHAR, @ESIC, @UAN, @SALARY, @DIVISION, @BRANCH, @USER, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
END
```

EmployeeP1 structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeP1]
(
    [EmployeeID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Emp_ID] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [isActive] [bit] NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [BirthDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Gender] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [FatherName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [MotherName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Address1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Address2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Address3] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Pin_Code] [numeric](6, 0) NULL,
    [DistrictID] [int] NULL,
    [StateID] [int] NULL,
    [Mobile] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [Mobile2] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [AccountName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [BankAccount] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [IfscCode] [nvarchar](11) NULL,
    [PermanentAccount] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [AadharNumber] [nvarchar](14) NULL,
    [JoiningDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [ESIC] [nchar](12) NULL,
    [Esic_Joining_Date] [date] NULL,
    [UAN] [nchar](12) NULL,
    [UAN_Joining_Date] [date] NULL,
    [EPF_ID] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [SalaryID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DivisionID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BranchID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AccessBy] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LastUsed] [datetime] NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [EmployeeID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The input as with bulk insert is like below :

[image: With Bulk Insert the auto increment is not updating after 10 serials]

Expect the serial increment for all the record inserted with bulk import

Comment: A little unclear.  Add the create table script for `EmployeeP1`, and add example data showing what it currently does vs what you want it to do.

Comment: question updated

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up.  Looks like Mudassir has you covered.  Either modify the table to store `Emp_Id` as `int` (or another numeric data type) or change your script to `...select max(cast(emp_id as int)) + 1...`.  I'd recommend the first option assuming you can modify the table.

Comment: @AaronDietz thanks for your valuable comment and the same is working like PRO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EmpId is nvarchar, so when it's value reaches 10, the max value remains 9 as in character comparison 9 is greater than 10 so you will keep getting 9 + 1 as next value.

Also you already have Employee ID column in table with auto incrementing values so I don't think EmpId column is required.

Comment: here the Emp_ID is nvarchar but i store its value from `@tagid` value not the same empid value. as per statement the `max(emp_id)` is 10 and after increment it assign to `@tagid` and after that stored in table data.

Comment: Thanks for Reply but the other Emp_ID for manual entry by user end and EmployeeID for database auto increment

Comment: Check Aaron Deitz comment..change your query as written by him

Answer (score 0):

The concept has been answered, however I am adding a "safety" condition in the where clause. (thus my new answer)

Generic Northwind example where the column is a string-column BUT has int values.

```
  SELECT MAX(CAST(PostalCode as INT)) + 1 as NextValue FROM dbo.Customers 
    WHERE 
        ISNUMERIC(PostalCode) > 0 /* protect against non int values in a string column */
```

Probably your query:

```
  SELECT MAX(CAST(Emp_Id as INT)) + 1 as NextValue FROM dbo.EmployeeP1 
    WHERE 
        ISNUMERIC(Emp_Id) > 0 /* protect against non int values in a string
```